# Freezing/fixing cells into position?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a lookup section to the right of around 6 sheets on my Excel document, all different - I'd like to have them fixed in position, so for example cells L2 to P19 would show up no matter how far I scrolled down the document.

Is anything like that possible? I've tried freezing panes and adding a split, but they don't do quite what I'm after (they either just fix horizontally/vertically, not just fix some cells in position permanently).

Answer (score 1):

You have not clarified quite why just splitting does not suit, so exactly what you would like is not clear to me but an alternative to freezing/splitting could be to add a New Window:

[image: SU463399 example]